# Как нескольким пользователям дать доступ к хостингу, но только к определенным папкам?

Tags: php, html, ftp, хостинг

Вот например у меня на хосте есть папка views и scripts я сам программист и у меня есть верстальщик и я хочу чтобы он имел доступ только к папке views.

Comment: Какой хостинг ?

Comment: Вы собираетесь редактировать сайт прямо на продакшене, что ли?

Comment: а что не так???

Comment: ho.ua хостингг гг

Comment: @Erepaha да всё не так, 2017 год, уже придумали более удобные и надежные способы. А если кто-то из вас неосторожным движением удалит файлы, продакшен ляжет, да?

Answer (score 0):

Данную информацию лучше уточнять у вашего хостинг-провайдера. Например, если вы пользуетесь FTP доступом, то как правило почти каждый хостинг имеет возможность дать доступ на отдельного пользователя к определенной папке. Вот и создайте FTP пользователя с доступом только на папку views